# Return Dictionary from a list using username

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I created a function to return dictionary object. I can't call it with the username but get the following error:
`'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'`

```py
def find_user(df_dict, filter_string):
    filtered_dict = dict(filter(lambda item: filter_string in item[0], df_dict.items()))

    return filtered_dict

find_user(df_dict=reviewers_dicts['Username'], filter_string='krpz1113')
```

Comment: What does your `reviewers_dicts` look like? and Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: {"Username": "bkpn1412", "DOB": "31.07.1983", "State": "Oregon", "Reviewed": ["cea76118f6a9110a893de2b7654319c0"]}

Comment: I get different exception : `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things wrong here:

1. `reviewers_dicts['Username']` gives you a string `"bkpn1412"` and it doesn't have `.items()` attribute.
2. You want to check the `filter_string` against the `"Username"` key in the dictionary not checking if the dictionary has `filter_string`.
3. As your function's name suggest, you want to *find* a user, not getting a list/dict of users(presumably usernames are unique.)

Here is the solution:

```py
def find_user(list_of_dicts, filter_string):
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        if d["Username"] == filter_string:
            return d


reviewers_dicts = [
    {
        "Username": "bkpn1412",
        "DOB": "31.07.1983",
        "State": "Oregon",
        "Reviewed": ["cea76118f6a9110a893de2b7654319c0"],
    },
    {
        "Username": "krpz1113",
        "DOB": "21.17.1989",
        "State": "Oregon",
        "Reviewed": ["jh5b34jh5b3jh5b34jh5b3hj5b3b5jh34"],
    },
]
print(find_user(list_of_dicts=reviewers_dicts, filter_string="krpz1113"))
```